# Is there a good way to validate that all inputs to a function have compatible sizes when using a (Repeating) arguments block?

Tags: matlab, variadic-functions, argument-validation

## Setup

Let's say I have some function that a number of arrays as an input and does something with them that requires the arrays to have compatible sizes (i.e., to have the same sizes after implicit singleton dimension expansion). I have written a function `mustBeCompatibleSize` that throws an error if it's arguments have incompatible sizes. This works as expected. It correctly points out which argument is causing the error to the user.

```matlab
function multiArrayOperation1(Array1, Array2, Array3)
    arguments
        Array1;
        Array2 {mustBeCompatibleSize(Array1, Array2)};
        Array3 {mustBeCompatibleSize(Array1, Array2, Array3)};
    end
    % Do something with Array1, Array2, and Array3.
end
```

For example, calling `multiArrayOperation1(ones(5, 1), ones(1, 5), ones(5, 6))` will result in MATLAB telling the user that the 3rd argument was not compatible with previous arguments.

## Issue

The issue comes about when I want to make a function that accepts any number of input arrays, using the (Repeating) arguments block, like in the example below. This example does not work, as the argument validator passes only one element at a time into the `mustBeCompatibleSize` function, and thus no error is thrown.

```matlab
function multiArrayOperation2(Arrays)
    arguments (Repeating)
        Arrays {mustBeCompatibleSize};
    end
    % Do something with Arrays.
end
```

For example, calling `multiArrayOperation2(ones(5, 1), ones(1, 5), ones(5, 6))` does not result in an error being thrown.

## Nonoptimal Solution

Of course, we can just call the validation function manually after the arguments block. However, this does not display to the user which argument is causing the error as it does in the first example, and doesn't really utilize the arguments block for validation.

```matlab
function multiArrayOperation3(Arrays)
    arguments (Repeating)
        Arrays;
    end

    mustBeCompatibleSize(Arrays{:});

    % Do something with Arrays.
end
```

For example, calling `multiArrayOperation3(ones(5, 1), ones(1, 5), ones(5, 6))` throws an error as it should, but the user is not informed which specific argument is causing the error.

## Question

Is there a better solution to this issue? Hopefully, there is a way to implement something similar to the second example.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice question! I haven't used this form of argument validation, but from the documention it seems it is not designed to do what you want, i.e. having an `arguments` block of dynamic size. or being able to dynamically refer to previous arguments in the validation of each one

Comment: Can you do `function multiArrayOperation(Array1, OtherArrays)`, and then `Arrays {@(arr) mustBeCompatibleSize(Array1, arr)};`? Oh, I see the example you give, being compatible with the first array wouldn't be enough of a test.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm guessing Luis is right, that this is probably not an intended feature of the arguments block. Cris, that's a clever idea except, as you noted, it won't always work when checking for compatible sizes. However, it could be useful if the function was checking for something like equally-sized arguments instead.